# Camera limitation over the Y-Axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

Im trying to limit the player camera so the camera wont wont be able to rotate 360.
This is what I was trying to make, but for some reason when the newRorationX reaches to 0. it clamp to his max value;
when the value newRorationX reach 80 then he reaches the max and stops the player from continue looking further down ( the right behaviour). but when he start looking up - and newRorationX reaches to 0, it set back to 80 and the player looks down.

What am I doing wrong?

```
       private void RotateBodyWithMouse()
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
            {
                Vector2 mouseInput = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X"), -Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y"));

                transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseInput.x * _mouseSensitivity.x * Time.deltaTime);
                float newRotationX = _currentCamera.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x + (mouseInput.y * _mouseSensitivity.y * Time.deltaTime);
                newRotationX = Mathf.Clamp(newRotationX, -80, 80);
                 _currentCamera.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(newRotationX, _currentCamera.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, _currentCamera.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In general do not use [`eulerAngles`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html) for reading access ->

> `When you read the .eulerAngles property, Unity converts the Quaternion's internal representation of the rotation to Euler angles. Because, there is more than one way to represent any given rotation using Euler angles, the values you read back out may be quite different from the values you assigned. This can cause confusion if you are trying to gradually increment the values to produce animation.`

Instead you can simply track the amount you already rotated and do e.g.

```
private float xRotation;

private void RotateBodyWithMouse()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
    {
        var mouseInput = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X"), -Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y"));

        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseInput.x * _mouseSensitivity.x * Time.deltaTime);

        xRotation += mouseInput.y * _mouseSensitivity.y * Time.deltaTime;
        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -80, 80);
         _currentCamera.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

---

If it is really necessary to keep also track of original camera orientation then instead do

```
private Quaternion originalCamRotation;
private float xRotation;

private void Start()
{
    originalCamRotation = _currentCamera.transform.rotation;
}

private void RotateBodyWithMouse()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
    {
        var mouseInput = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X"), -Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y"));

        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseInput.x * _mouseSensitivity.x * Time.deltaTime);

        xRotation += mouseInput.y * _mouseSensitivity.y * Time.deltaTime;
        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -80, 80);
         _currentCamera.transform.rotation = originalCamRotation * Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

As the name suggests there are multiple cameras you might want to store those in a dictionary then.

Answer (score 1):

That behavior is in this line:

```
float newRotationX = _currentCamera.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x + (mouseInput.y * _mouseSensitivity.y * Time.deltaTime);
```

why, the `_currentCamera.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x`, go from 0-360, and when it reach 360, it goes back to 0, yes? So as per the Clamp function behavior, 0 is clamp to -80, and the camera looks down.

What you need to do, is delete the

```
newRotationX = Mathf.Clamp(newRotationX, -80, 80);
```

The clamp function itself, indeed. Already, in your calculation:

```
(mouseInput.y * _mouseSensitivity.y * Time.deltaTime);
```

the mouseInput have been always clamped already from -1 to 1, so your result is confined between
-mouseInput.y and mouseInput.y in and of itself. Cheers!